# Bootstrap dropdown not working after close bootstrap modal in razor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4

My Bootstrap dropdown not working after close bootstrap modal.
Modal:

```
   <span class="btn btn-warning btn-sm col-xs-offset-5 col-xs-1"
              id="backFromEdit" data-dismiss="modal">
            &#x2718;
        </span>
```

dropdown:

```
 <div class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    @User.Identity.GetUserName()
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Manage Account", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })</li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

The modal contains a partial view and dropdown is in partial view login.
Actually the dropdown starts working on every second time closing the modal(e.g. not working after 1st 3rd 5th close... but work on 2nd, 4th...). Very weird. I came across the same situation if I use .modal('toggle') instead of data-dismiss="modal".
Anyone knows about this?

Comment: You have to clearly state the issue. including a  fiddle, will surely help. What is `drop`?

Answer (score 2):

It is too late but for someone who comes back to this, this happens when bootstrap.js is bound twice. At times when the parent page has reference to bootstrap.js and the modal as well; in that case the click event is not released to parent page.
refer to... [Issue reported earlier](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/13833)

Comment: This is a valid answer, it made me look at my project and I found that I included bootstrap twice, now it works!